# Can't index of the "#[hello]" in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, unix

The following `index_of` function doesn't work for all cases:

```
#!/bin/bash

index_of() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"
    
    local prefix=${string/${search_string}*/}
    
    local index=${#prefix}
     
    if [[ index -eq ${#string} ]];
    then
        index=-1
    fi
    
    printf "%s" "$index"
}

a='#[hello] world'

b=$(index_of "$a" "world")
echo "A: $b"

b=$(index_of "$a" "hello")
echo "B: $b"

b=$(index_of "$a" "#[hello]")
echo "C: $b"
```

Here is the output:

```
A: 9
B: 2
C: -1
```

The `A` and `B` is correct, but the `C` is incorrect.

The `C` should be `0` instead of `-1`.

What's wrong in the `index_of` function and how to fix the `C` index?

Comment: What is index_of function supposed to do? `[[ index -eq` Why are you comparing the _string_ `index` numerically with anything?

Comment: I want to implement the same String.indexOf() function in Java by using bash. And use this index_of in my bash script.

Comment: What KamilCuk means: `index` is a character string, but not a variable whose content is compared. You forgot a dollar sign.

Comment: Instead of `[[ $index -eq ${#string} ]];` you can use `(( index == ${#string} ))`.  `((..))` enters math mode.

Comment: I tried but it is the same. I found a problem: `local prefix=${string/${search_string}*/}` this `prefix` returns the full string when the `search_string` is at the first position. It is not the expected behavior. Is it a **BUG** of bash?

Comment: it's `${parameter/pattern/string}`, so second parameter is a patter, so you have to escape special chars.

Comment: Try `printf -v search_string '%q' "$2"` instead of `search_string="$2"`. This will escape special characters `#`, `[` and `]`.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, I tried your solution, it works and I don't need to escape anything. Does it mean I don't need to escape anything when passing the arguments? Is it suitable for all cases?

Comment: It is the `%q` format specifier that does the job (see `man bash` and search for `printf`). Does it work in all cases? I think so but honestly I do not no for sure, you'll have to do some tests.

Comment: I did some tests. It should work if `search_string` contains only visible ASCII characters (ASCII codes 32 to 126) and does not start with a `%`. If there is a possibility that `search_string` starts with a `%` it must be escaped. Simply add `search_string="${search_string/#%/\\%}"` after `printf -v search_string '%q' "$2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using parameter expansion in the `pattern` part of constructs like `${param/pattern/repl}`, quote the parameter expansion to remove the special meaning of any shell pattern metacharacters that may exist in the parameter.

Here's a slightly different implementation of your `index_of` function. In case the length of the second argument is zero, the index shall be zero. At the end, a return value is provided to indicate success or failure. `"$2"` is quoted in `${1/"$2"*/}` so it is treated literally, not as a shell pattern.

```
#! /bin/bash -

index_of () {
    local idx pfx

    pfx=${1/"$2"*/}
    idx=$((${#1} == ${#pfx} ? -!!${#2} : ${#pfx}))

    printf '%s\n' "$idx"
    return "$((idx < 0))"
}

for str in world hello '#[hello]'; do
    index_of '#[hello] world' "$str"
done
```

output:

```
9
2
0
```

Comment: ++ve for very nice answer, Good to see in pure bash, cheers.

Comment: I tried your solution, it even works for this test `$(index_of "%[hello] world" "%[hello]")` as mentioned in the @RenaudPacalet's reply. I accepted this as the true answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

index_of() {
    local string="$1"
    local search_string="$2"

    local prefix=${string/${search_string}*/}

    local index=${#prefix}

    if [[ $index -eq ${#string} ]];
    then
        index=-1
    fi

    printf "%s" "$index"
}

a='#[hello] world'

b=$(index_of "$a" "world")
echo "A: $b"

b=$(index_of "$a" "hello")
echo "B: $b"

b=$(index_of "$a" "\#\[hello\]")
echo "C: $b"
```

result

```
A: 9
B: 2
C: 0
```